# Assembly Reference in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I build my Web App I get the following error.

```
The type or namespace name 'LoginViewModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
public class _Page_Views_Account_Login_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<LoginViewModel>
```

I open the file where the using is defined in AppData. I have that.

```
using Repository.Models;
```

This is the previous location of view model LoginViewModel.
Now this is another project named just ViewModel.
Each time when I build my application this old using is appear. Where can I set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Created another project to Store the LoginViewModel?
If So, You need to add reference to the new project.

Right Click on reference and Choose "Add Reference"
Select Project and Click on the project which contains the LoginViewModel.

Sorry i can't send Snapshot right now. Hope it helps.